# Can not uninstall Homebrew

Tags: homebrew

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBt4o.png)I had an unsafe and incomplete installation of homebrew and now want to completely remove it. When I tried the command given on the official website, the terminal got stuck. I tried to use brew doctor to figure out what the problem was, as shown in the figure.
By the way, when installing gaming-porting-toolkits before, I also used the command ""arch -x86_64 zsh"" according to the documentation and then installed brew in the Rosetta environment. . .
In short, it is very confusing now. I want to completely delete homebrew but I don’t know how to do it. Please friends give me some guidance.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfoMN.png)

Way to completely delete homebrew, or can I manually delete which files to achieve the same effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew (or wherever you installed HB)
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

If you had added Homebrew's binary path to your shell profile (like .bash_profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc.), you'd want to remove it. Typically, it looks like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Launch Terminal in Rosetta mode (Applications -> Utilities, find the Terminal app, right-click on it, choose Get Info, and check the box for "Open using Rosetta")
Then, open the Terminal and repeat the removal steps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have followed all the instructions, but how do I know that I have completely deleted brew to ensure that it will not conflict with downloading again?

Comment: You will only find out once you have attempted to install it anew.

Comment: @learning - please mark the answer as correct and upvote if it was helpful